# How can I place the same building repeatedly?

Tags: tropico-4

I would like to place the same building multiple times. For apartments, this is enabled by default, but for other buildings, I have to go through the build menu again.

Comment: the standard method for games for a long time was 'hold shift whilst placing', I assume this doesn't work. Tried ctrl or alt?

Comment: Yes, none of those work ;(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some largely undocumented controls that might be useful, taken from [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/57690/discussions/0/864946409177353109/) and [here](http://www.strategynerd.com/page/Tropico-4-Guide.aspx).

- Last Constructed Building: <kbd>\</kbd>
- Cycle between building variants (e.g. different types of farms): <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>
- Rotate camera: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>
- Zoom in and out: <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>
- Rotate buildings: <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>
- Demolish: <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Last On-Screen Notification: <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Open Almanac: <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Road: <kbd>R</kbd>
- Select Avatar: <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Comment: Wow, F1 is a livesaver!

Answer (score 1):

As a preliminary answer, several buildings are accessible via a keyboard shortcut. For instance, roads can be selected by pressing 'R', garages by 'G'.